# Micro SD Card not detected anymore on Redmi note 11 pro, not accessible from computer

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd

I've installed a micro SD card on my phone, as an extension of the internal storage, but it's not detected anymore on my phone...

With some tools on the computer I found out that the micro SD card is divided into 2 partitions, android meta and android expand. I guess it's partitions for android extension storage.

How can I make it work again? Is there something to fix this? I need to recover files on it, and it is super boring to use weird software...

Comment: If you have formatted the SD-card as internal storage the data is encrypted, so recovery software is not an option.

Comment: so what's the option?

Comment: If your device is not rooted the only way is to read the sd-card inside your phone. If that doesn't work I don't see a way to access the data anymore.

Comment: So do you think i should root my phone?

Comment: For rooting your phone you need to unlock the bootloader which will erase all user data including the encryption keys. If you do that you can be 100% sure the SD-card data is gone.